# UICollectionView Pagination - How to get the last visible cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a `UICollectionView`, where it contains 2 cells per row. Now, I need to enable paging, where when the last cell of the `UICollectionView` appears I need to fetch another set of records. How can I get this done.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        MyCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cc" forIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (indexPath.row == [mydictionary count]) {
                pg = pg +1;

               [self loadtheservice:pg];

            }


return cell;
}
```

According to my above code, the `[self loadtheservice:pg]` gets called many times. I think the reason is that the final cell is being `visible` for a long and the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is calling the load service method. How can I solve this?

Comment: Try moving your condition and loading to `- (void)collectionView (UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` or `didDisplayCell:`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `willDisplayCell` method to check condition which available form iOS8

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Bellow IOS8: 
Generally  we use following. Yes it will call each scroll end so it may not preferred.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

So if you don't want that you can manage that with UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegates. I am giving rough idea. You can implement according to your requirement.Using following,

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if(paging does not complete ) {
            // you can give some nice gui to load more to notify user. if you dont want to notify user, just return with 1px height size 
          } else {
              return zero size 
          }   
     }
```

you can manage that view from following deligates

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if(kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
     // here you can add your nice load more functionality with some custom view . if you dont need load more view, you can add 1px height footer view and manage that if paging completed 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use willDisplayCell method to check condition which available form iOS8

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for below iOS8 versions you need check condition on scrollViewDidEndDecelerating method like below

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
        if (bottomEdge >= self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height) {
           //here call API to load next page records
        }

}
```

Comment: `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating ` is not the solution. It gets executed every time the scroll stops. I need to find the last cell loading in this problem

Comment: yes it will call every time the scroll stops but we need to add proper conditions.